# Pass template function to std::bind?

Tags: c++, templates, bind

I want to use std::bind with template function. Is it somehow possible?

P.S. It is IMPORTANT to use `std::bind`, because I know at least one solution through lambdas and want to find out if there is std::bind solution.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct foo : std::enable_shared_from_this<foo>
{
    void f()
    {
        // doesn't compile, error : no matching function for call to 'bind'
        auto cb = std::bind(&foo::handle, shared_from_this(), placeholders::_1, placeholders::_2);
    }

    template <typename T, typename U>
    void handle(T, U)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why you cannot use lambda?

Comment: `&foo::handle<int, int>` would be possible, but types would be fixed.

Comment: This will work with lambdas, so if you indeed have a use-case where you think you can't use it you should probably present why.

Comment: its not a "template function", but a "function template". This distinction is actually important here, because `handle` is not a function, it is a template. You can only `std::bind` to a function (eg to `foo::handle<int,int>`), but not to a template

Comment: If you really need to use `std::bind`, then the solution is actually *lambdas*. Instead of using the member function use a lambda. Like `auto cb = std::bind([this](auto&& a, auto&& b) { handle(a, b); }, placeholders::_1, placeholders::_2);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`handle` is not a template function. There are no "template functions". `handle` is a function template, ie it is a template, it is not a function. You cannot `std::bind` to a template. You can only `std::bind` to a callable.

The trick is to defer instantiation of the template and deduction of the template parameters to when the function is actually called:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct foo {

    struct handle_caller {
        template <typename T,typename U>
        void operator()(foo* f, T t,U u){
            f->handle(t,u);
        }
    };

    void f()
    {
        auto cb = std::bind(handle_caller{},this, placeholders::_1, placeholders::_2);
    }

    template <typename T, typename U>
    void handle(T, U)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The callable passed to bind is an object of a concrete type `handle_caller`. It is not a template. Only when `cb` is called the parameters are forwarded to `handle_caller::operator()` where the template arguments can be deduced.

Lambdas can do this out-of-the box, because a lambda with `auto` arguments is of a concrete type and only its `operator()` is a template:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct foo {
    void f()
    {
        auto cb = std::bind([](auto f,auto t,auto u){ f->handle(t,u);},this, placeholders::_1, placeholders::_2);
    }

    template <typename T, typename U>
    void handle(T, U)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

However, once you use the lambda there is no need for `std::bind` anymore, because you can bind the parameters via a lambda capture. `std::bind` is the ancient way to bind parameters, it is convoluted and has clunky syntax. I have read of cases that can be done with `std::bind` but not with a lambda, but I have never encountered one.

PS: Note that I removed the `shared_from_this` stuff from your code, because I know it can be used wrong easily, but I am not sure how to use it correctly. As `cb` is only local to `foo::f` there is no need to worry about the lifetime of `this` in the example code.

Answer (score 0):

`&foo::handle` is not valid C++, because `foo::handle` is not a function. `foo::handle<int, int>` is a function, and `foo::handle<double, std::string>` is a different function.

You will have to wrap it in *something*, so you may as well use a lambda.